# Directory Not Found Exception...yet I can browse to the directory?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my asp.net page I'm making a copy of a file from my local drive to the server.

```
'append the name to the id number and generate the file name
strFileName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("strAttachmentsPath") & l.ToString & "_" & CType(Session("FileName"), String)
'upload the file
'FileUpload1.SaveAs(strFileName)

System.IO.File.Copy(CType(Session("Attachment"), String), strFileName, True)
```

`strFileName` contains a server path like `"\\myServer\images\theNewFileName.jpg"`
`Session("Attachment")` contains my local path `'C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\AccountsFrance.txt'`

But when I run this code asp.net throws an exception:

But I can browse to this file easily....
I dont understand why this is happening :(

[image]

Comment: It's most likely that it is a permissions issue. Or, that you are using a different filepath then what you really intended.

Comment: @rlb.usa - not sure how to overcome this...as I cannot set the fileupload control to take a string programitically for security reasons.  I need to allow the end user to copy a file from one path to a server.  That path could be their local PC c/d/e drive, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming permissions are set for Network Service to write the destination directory, do a

`strFileName = Server.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("strAttachmentsPath") & l.ToString & "_" & CType(Session("FileName"), String))`

to the directory and see if you still get the permissions problem.

Also, what is the value of Session("Attachment") ?  That needs to be a file path on the server, not the user's side.  Typically, in upload scenarios, you take the byte[] from the upload control and write it to a stream on the server.  You could then take that file path and copy it somewhere else.

Comment: @Josh I tried that with no error, but of course I commented out copying the file how does this help me?

Comment: When dealing with ASP.NET pages, you have to let the server place the file according to what it knows.  That is what Server.MapPath does.  Try the copy and see what happens.

Comment: @Josh when I uncommented the copy `System.IO.File.Copy(CType(Session("Attachment"), String), strFileName, True)` and right above that was this `Server.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("strAttachmentsPath") & l.ToString & "_" & CType(Session("FileName"), String))` I get the same error :(

Comment: Does Network Service have write permissions to directory that strFileName points to?

Comment: @Josh when I look at that folder '\\myServer\images\theNewFileName.jpg' it has both network and network service and they both have write permissions.  Is that what you are referring to ?

Comment: Yes.  What is the value of Session("Attachment")?  Does that point to a file on the server or the client?

Comment: Session attachment has the value on the client side: 'C:\myUser\...'.

Comment: ASP.NET cannot access that file.  Your upload control most likely has a byte[] that gets the uploaded file.  Take that byte array and write it out to the server.

Comment: The issue is I dont have the file upload control on this screen.  I response.redirect to a new page and store in a session variable the path of the file the user wants to upload.  Then I use `file.copy` to copy it.  I cannot add a fileupload control and set it to invisible on this new page because I cannot programitically set the file name for security reasons.  ASP.net does not allow you to do that.  I have pasted an image of a watch window for you on my original question

Comment: This won't work.  You will need to upload the file on the page that contains the upload control, then redirect.  The byte[] only exists on this posted back (assuming webforms) page.  You cannot go back, after the fact and get the file off the user's machine.  Break on the page that has the upload control and inspect the control for a byte[] that contains the file.  You will have to handle it there.

Comment: err... this isnt possible but I will take another look at it..maybe I can change some things...